# How can I have different backgrounds on different computers?

Tags: windows, windows-8, sync, themes, microsoft-account

So I have two Windows 8 VMs. I want to set one's theme to blue/black colors and the others to red colors.

The reason I want these different is that I will be using the VMs simultaneously. One is 32 bit, and the other is 64 bit. I want to have an immediate indication of which VM I am on so that I don't make mistakes where I'm on the wrong machine.

When trying to change the theme, Windows and it's magical syncing changes it across every computer I have running Windows 8. How can I tell Windows not to do this?

Comment: Do you have to use a MS live account? Can you create separate local accounts?

Comment: @BradPatton I use a MS live account. I can create separate accounts, but I'd strongly rather not since theme stuff is the only thing I don't want to sync

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can configure what is synced on the PC Settings screen.

For Windows 8:

1. <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to get to settings
2. Select `Sync your settings`.
3. Set `Personalize` to `Off` to not sync the background.

For Windows 10:

1. Open Settings (`Start`->`Settings` or <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>)
2. Select `Accounts`
3. Select `Sync your settings`
4. Turn `Theme` off

Comment: In case you find the instructions unclear: 1) `Windows+I` 2) `PC settings` down at the bottom 3) Search `sync` 4) select `sync settings` 5) you're welcome.